# Лог нанесённого урона

Tags: php, разработка-игр

Многие текстовые игры используют лог, где отображается нанесённый урон в виде строк, и в тоже время он сохраняет результат.

К примеру:

> Вы нанесли урон 1
>
> Вы нанесли урон 1
>
> Вы нанесли урон 1
>
> Враг нанес вам урон 2

Но лог имеет ограничения, в 10 строк, то есть каждая первая строка заменяется на новое значение, 10 стирается и туда помещается ранее 9 я строка. Как они это сделали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лог сообщений где-то хранится (в базе, например, или в сессии), а когда строится для вывода, выбираются только последние N сообщений.

---

[Пример на php](https://3v4l.org/3Gsii):

```
interface ICache {
    public function has($key);
    public function get($key);
    public function set($key, $val);
}
class Cache implements ICache {
    private $storage = [];
    public function has($key) {return isset($this->storage[$key]);}
    public function get($key) {return $this->storage[$key];}
    public function set($key, $val) {$this->storage[$key] = $val;}
}

class SessionCache implements ICache {
    public function has($key) {return isset($_SESSION[$key]);}
    public function get($key) {return $_SESSION[$key];}
    public function set($key, $val) {$_SESSION[$key] = $val;}
}

class BattleLog{
    private $storage;
    private $key;
    private $length;
    public function __construct(ICache $storage, $N, $id) {
        $this->storage = $storage;
        $this->length = $N;
        $this->key = 'battle_log_'.$id;
        if (!$this->storage->has($this->key)) {
            $this->storage->set($this->key, []);
        }
    }
    public function log($message) {
        $log = $this->storage->get($this->key);
        array_unshift($log, $message);
        $log = array_slice($log, 0, $this->length);
        $this->storage->set($this->key, $log);
    }

    public function render() {
        $log = $this->storage->get($this->key);
        foreach ($log as $message) {
            echo "$message\n";
        }
    }
}

$log = new BattleLog(new Cache, 3, 27);

$log->log('Вы нанесли урон 1');
$log->log('Вы нанесли урон 1');
$log->log('Вы нанесли урон 2');
$log->log('Вы нанесли урон 3');
$log->log('Вы нанесли урон 5');
$log->log('Вы нанесли урон 8');
$log->log('Вы нанесли урон 13');

$log->render();
```

Осталось только реализовать более персистентное хранилище, чем `Cache`.

Comment: Добрый день, пожалуйста объясните как ваш код работает, я ещё ООП не изучал.

Comment: Основа кода это вдвигание значения в начало массива `array_unshift($log, $message)`, и обрезание массива по определённой длине `$log = array_slice($log, 0, $length)`

Comment: Спасибо я вас понял. Ещё пару вопросов это из-за this у вас получился  такой длинный код? Подскажите, лучше лог помещать в БД или сделать через сессию? А то думаю чтобы не слишком много обращений к БД было, или тут всё равно? К примеру сейчас, на одной странице требуется 3-4 обращений к БД, а кликать мне нужно часто.

Comment: Если лог боя одноразовый, я бы вообще на клиенте всё это рисовал, в базе этот лог точно не нужен.

Comment: Код длинный получился не из-за `$this`, а из-за необходимости где-то это всё хранить.